# Why the last section covers the above sections

Tags: javascript, html, css, sections, purejs-onepage-scroll

I am trying to create the full-page parallax scroll in the one-page website. There are 5 sections in the page. When I add the code of parallax scrolling, the last section covers the above sections. I am not sure where is the mistake.

And, I guess the js/jQuery code in my work does not work since the effects do not come out on the menu.

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you so much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let hamburgerClicked = fales;

  $('#toggle').on("click", function() {
    if (hamburgerClicked == false) {
      $(".top").css('transform', 'translate (11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg)');
      $(".bottom").css('transform', 'translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg)');

      hamburgerClicked = true;
    } else {
      $(".top").css('transform', 'translate (0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)');
      $(".bottom").css('transform', 'translateY (0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)');
      hamburgerClicked = false;
    }
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url(../img/background/background.png);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#meteor-shower {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.background {
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  height: 100vh 30vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(30vh);
  transition-timing-function: .2s all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0, 1);
}

.background:first-child {
  transform: translateY(-30vh / 2);
}

.content-wrapper {
  transform: translateY(30vh /2);
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(40vh);
  will-change: transform;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition-timing-function: 1.2s +.5, all, cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.44, 0.1);
  text-decoration: none;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


/*-------------------------------background-animation---------------------------------------*/

.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  display: block;
}

.twinkling {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent url(../img/background/2446101-03.png) repeat top center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-animation: move-twink-back 16s infinite;
  animation: move-twink-back 16s infinite;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}


/*----------------------------------------navbar---------------------------------------------*/


/*-------------header-container-------------*/

header {
  height: 3em;
  position: fixed;
}

.header-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-container h1 {
  font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: block;
}


/*-------------------menu-------------------*/

.button-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  content: "";
}

.button-container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.top:active {
  transform: translate(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom:active {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

span {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 4px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.middle {
  top: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: .6;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
}

li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  width: 30%;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
}


/*---------------------------------------section-1-------------------------------------------*/

#section1 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

#section1 {
  :nth-child(1) {
    padding-top: 0px;
    display: flex;
  }
}


/*------------crystal-animation-------------*/

#crstal-animation {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.crystal {
  width: 23%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 18%;
  left: 40%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
  animation: rotation 8s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotation {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  35% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg) rotateX(5deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 16px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  65% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-38deg) rotateX(2deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(16px 0px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  86% {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(1deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 10px 16px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(16px 16px 10px rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8));
  }
}


/*---------------------------------------section-2-------------------------------------------*/

#section2 {
  padding: 60px 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 59%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.content p {
  width: 88%;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content h2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.crystal-animation {
  width: 68%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -56%;
  margin-right: -80%;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
}

aside {
  display: block;
}


/*---------------------------------------section-3-------------------------------------------*/

#section3 {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

#section3:nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*--------constellation-cards----------*/

.gallery {
  list-style: none outside none;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

h2,
p {
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery li {
  margin: 10px;
}

.gallery li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1)
}

.svg {
  width: 75%;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px)rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -khtml-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}


/*---------------------------------------section-3-content---------------------------------*/


/*------------card-content-------------*/

#section3-content {
  flex: 90%;
  padding: 60px 130px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 100vh;
}

.intro h3 {
  font-family: 'Gabriela', serif;
}

.content-text {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.constellation-img {
  opacity: .35;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.constellation-star {
  width: 56%;
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  left: 1%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.intro {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-right: 100px;
}

.constellation-pattern {
  width: 11%;
  opacity: .9;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}

.intro p {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.constellation-icon li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.constellation-button {
  width: 13%;
  /*--------border: 2px solid opacity .3 #fff;
  background: opacity .3 #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;-----------*/
}


/*----------44--------------------------section-4------------------------------------------*/

#section4 {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  align-content: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.s3 {
  text-align: left;
}

.s3-content {
  width: 74%;
  padding-top: 16%;
  padding-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="twinkling"></div>

<header>
  <div class="header-container">
    <h1>Constellations</h1>
  </div>


  <div class="button-container" id="toggle">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
    <nav class="overlay-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#How to Find Constellations in the Night Sky?">Stargazing</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>


<div class="container">
  <section id="section1" class="background">
    <div id="crystal-animation">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/crystal.svg" alt="" class="crystal">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section id="section2" class="background">
    <article class="content">
      <h2>What is Constellations?</h2>
      <p>Constellations are patterns in the night sky often formed by the most prominent stars to the naked eye. </p>

      <p>Constellations often carry names and take the shape of gods, hunters, princesses, objects and mythical beasts associated with Greek mythology – however, at times, it requires quite an imagination to draw out what some constellations are supposed
        to represent! </p>
      <aside><img src="img/crystal-animation.svg" alt="" class="crystal-animation"></aside>
    </article>
  </section>


  <!-- section-3---->
  <section id="section3" class="background">

    <h2>12 Constellations</h2>
    <p>Click the constellation cards and understand more.</p>
    <div class="card">
      <ul class="gallery">
        <li>
          <figcaption>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/1.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
          </figcaption>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/4.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/7.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/10.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/2.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/5.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/8.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/11.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="gallery">
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/3.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/6.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/9.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-cards/12.svg" alt="" class="svg"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section id="section3-content" class="background">

    <div class="content-text">
      <img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Aries-img.svg" alt="" class="constellation-img"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Aries-star.svg" alt="" class="constellation-star">
      <article class="intro">
        <img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Aries-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-pattern">
        <h3>Aries</h3>
        <p>While one of the biggest, most famous, and oldest named constellations, Aquarius is faint and often hard to find/see. In Greek mythology, Aquarius represented Ganymede, a very handsome young man. Zeus recognized the lad’s good looks, and invited
          Ganymede to Mt. Olympus to be the cupbearer of the gods. For his service he was granted eternal youth, as well as a place in the night sky.
        </p>
        <p>Despite its prominent position and large size, you can see that Aquarius doesn’t really have defining features, nor does it contain any bright stars. The protruding line to the right is Aquarius’s right arm, with the large downward shape being
          a combination of the water flowing down out of the vase and his right leg. While not the entire constellation, what’s drawn above is what you’re most likely to see in the night sky. You won’t see this one in the city; you’ll need a dark sky
          to find the cupbearer.
        </p>
      </article>
      <div class="button">
        <ul class="constellation-icon">
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Aries-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Leo-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Sagittarius-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Taurus-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Virgo-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Capricorn-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Gemini-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Libra-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Aquarius-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Cancer-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Pisces-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"><img src="img/12-constellation-pattern/Scorpio-pattern.svg" alt="" class="constellation-button"></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- section-4---->

  <section id="section4" class="background">
    <div class="s3-content">
      <h2>How to Find Constellations in the Night Sky?</h2>
      <p class="s3">Using a star map will be your best bet for assisting in finding where to look for constellations, depending on your location and time of year. It’s different depending on where you live and on the seasons. You can also need the additional app to
        help find the constellations, that lets you enter your location and gives you a customized star map. </p>

      <p class="s3">All you need is a dark sky, so as far away from cities as possible, and for extra visual aide, a pair of binoculars or a telescope. With binoculars or a telescope, you’ll see fainter stars and other features like nebulae and star clusters. When
        you’re out observing, you’ll want to generally orient yourself towards the North Star.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: `let hamburgerClicked = fales;` <- Typo to `false`?

Comment: Thank you. I have corrected it. But it still does not work.

Comment: The responsive menu